# Adding data to Access Database through Visual Basic Form

Tags: database, visual-studio, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a forum where I want the user to type a profile name and then click Add and then it will add what they typed in the text box the the ProfileName field in my table. When I click the Add button, it comes up with an error that says An unhandled exception of type `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException` occurred in system.data.dll. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub RefreshData()
    Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnn.Open()
    End If
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT id AS [ID], " & _
        "ProfileName AS [Name] " & _
        " FROM Profile ORDER BY id", cnn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    cnn.Close()
    Me.dgvData.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)                 Handles Button1.Click
    If (TextBox1.Text = "") Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a profile name.")
    Else
        Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsof… Source=c:\Data\Database.mdb     ;Extended Properties=Paradox 5.x;")
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cnn.Open()
        End If

        cmd.Connection = cnn
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Profile(ProfileName) " & _
            "VALUES (" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cnn.Close()
        Dim oForm As addsnake
        oForm = New addsnake
        oForm.Show()
        oForm = Nothing
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the exact, full, error message and does it take you to a particular line in your code?

Comment: All that is on the dialog box is "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in system.data.dll" and the buttons are Break, Continue, Ignore (greyed out) and Help (help just prompts me for a disc and tries to go for a web page) It does not go to a line of code which is weird because it normally does.

Comment: Here is a picture of the error.
http://i42.tinypic.com/dnmywg.png

Comment: So when you press Break what line does it take you to?

Comment: No line. It comes up with this second error. 
http://i39.tinypic.com/aoatfq.png

Comment: Could you take a look at my other question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904868/populating-datagrid-in-visual-studio-from-access-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further information I suggest that:

You don't need to give id an alias of ID:

```
SELECT id AS [ID]
```

you might still enclose it in square-brackets though, if you like:

```
SELECT [id]
```

You are missing an apostrophe in the following line:

```
"VALUES (" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "')"
```

Also check your connection string at [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: Did everything you suggested, but I'm still getting the error :/

Comment: @JamesConroy Have you tried with: `"VALUES ('" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "')"` ... a single quote before the textbox text and another single quote after?

Comment: I just tried it now and it fixed everything :D You sir, are a genius thank you so much :DD
Now would you mind taking a look at my other problem? hehe
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904868/populating-datagrid-in-visual-studio-from-access-database

Comment: @JamesConroy I looked at the other question but can't help there.  Re this answer, please click the check mark near the top left of the answer to "accept" it.  You get points, Andy gets points, and everyone else will know your question has been resolved.  Thanks.