# Populating DataGrid in Visual Studio from Access Database?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a datagrid in my form. What I did was I made an OleDb connection to my database in access, then I made a dataset in my project and put my Food table in that. Then on the page that contains the form, I added a dataset (dataset11) from the Data Toolbox that links to dataset1.xsd in my project. I then put the data source on my datagrid to dataset11.Food (Food being the table I want to display). This adds the two fields in that table to the datagrid (id and size) but none of the data I put in in access shows up! There are 15 entries in this table but they don't show up on my datagrid even when I run the program. What am I doing wrong???!?!!?!?!?

Here is a picture: http://i39.tinypic.com/2rr43yf.png

[image]

**Edit** added code from external link

```
Me.DataGrid1.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Tag", Me.Dataset11, "Food.Size"))
Me.DataGrid1.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("DataSource", Me.Dataset11, "Profile.ProfileName"))
Me.DataGrid1.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("DataMember", Me.Dataset11, "Profile.ProfileName"))
Me.DataGrid1.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Visible", Me.Dataset11, "Profile.ProfileName"))
Me.DataGrid1.DataMember = ""
Me.DataGrid1.DataSource = Me.Dataset11.Profile
Me.DataGrid1.HeaderForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText
Me.DataGrid1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(296, 8)
Me.DataGrid1.Name = "DataGrid1"
Me.DataGrid1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(384, 256)
Me.DataGrid1.TabIndex = 12
```

Comment: Does your code do a DataBind()?

Comment: I am using the visual studio tools that generate the code for you. What DataBindings would I put in?

Comment: I tried putting in DataSouce, DataMember, Tag, and Visible bindings. Are there any I have to put in in order for it to display the data?

Comment: Right click on your form. I believe you'll see View Code. Click on that and make sure that after your DataSource is set, there is a line that calls DataBind()

Comment: I looked in the generated code, this is what I found, (no DataBind but rather DataBindings.add)

http://freetexthost.com/earq40bngb
(Had to use a different website because text was too long to fit in this box)

Comment: @JamesConroy in the future just edit your question to add the additional information, code in the comments is extremely hard and annoying to read and a lot of people will not click on external links.